# where to see a video map analysis?

Tags: starcraft-2

With 6th season start Blizzard displayed a review for 2 new maps: http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/blog/4469881/

Is there any resource where the same analysis done for all (some) other ladder maps?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done for various maps in the past by various casters. I don't think there's a centralized hub for them, but there is a good collection here [here](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=map%20rerview%20starcraft%202&oq=map%20rerview%20starcraft%202&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=477l645l0l741l2l2l0l0l0l0l86l130l2l2l0).